# Trouble understanding universal apps, multiple view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to figure out the best way to approach writing a universal app. I'm not sure how to  add some new files (for a new view), and how to add both iPhone and iPad view controllers. I'm using Xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty vague (and general), but does this tutorial give you the information you need? http://blog.corywiles.com/creating-a-universal-ios-app-tutorial